# How to annote a large file with mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

i'm trying to find out who did the last change on a certain line in a large xml file ( ~100.00 lines ).

I tried to use the log file viewer of thg but it does not give me any results.
Using `hg annote file.xml -l 95000 ..` took forever and eventually died with an error message.

Is there a way to annote a single line in a large file that does not take forever ?

Comment: "an error message" is not exactly a verbose description of what happend and leaves us with a lot of guessing, both as of the version of mercurial and what went wrong. The command you use(d) looks correct, though. If it is reproducable, you should consider a bug report for mercurial. Consider to also use --debug flag when calling mercurial for more verbose output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`hg grep`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#grep) to dig into a file if you have interest in very specific text:

```
hg grep "text-to-search" file.txt
```

You will likely need to add the `--all` switch to get every change that matches and then limit your results to a specific changeset range with `-r firstchage:lastchange` syntax.

I don't have a file on hand of the size you are working with, so this may also have trouble past a certain point, particularly if the search string matches many many lines in the file. But if you can get as specific as possible with your search string, you should be able to track it down.